Why gzip and pigz gives the same size of archives on different levels of compression?
I'm playing with gzip / pigz to concatenate files and forward output into the archive. It works, but I found these things weird:

gzip generates the same size of archive on levels -6 (default) and -9 (--best or maximum compression)
pigz also generates the same size of archive on levels -6 and -9
pigz generates larger archive comparing to gzip

Steps to reproduce (on Ubuntu 24.04):
# create 2 dummy files for tryouts:
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1024000000 > file1.txt
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1024000000 > file2.txt

# try various combinations for archiving:

# default gzip
cat file1.txt file2.txt | gzip -v > combined_default.txt.gz
# max compression gzip
cat file1.txt file2.txt | gzip -v -9 > combined_max.txt.gz

# parallel default compression
cat file1.txt file2.txt | pigz -v -p4 > combined_parralel_default.txt.gz
# parallel, max compression
cat file1.txt file2.txt | pigz -v -9 -p4 > combined_parralel_max.txt.gz

# list all files
ls -l

The output is :
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1556350976 Jun 16 13:11 combined_default.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1556350976 Jun 16 13:13 combined_max.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1558037995 Jun 16 13:15 combined_parralel_default.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1558037995 Jun 16 13:14 combined_parralel_max.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1024000000 Jun 16 13:07 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1024000000 Jun 16 13:07 file2.txt

Please, help me to understand:

why specifying the compression level doesn't affect the size of the final archive?
why pigz generates a larger archive while it is described as the parallel implementation of gzip and this imply obtaining the same result?


-6 and -9 change how hard the compressor looks for matching strings in the preceding data. However there effectively are no matching strings in random data. So there will be no difference.

The main difference between gzip and pigz here is that gzip is using 32K symbol deflate blocks, whereas pigz is using 16K symbols. This introduces a little more overhead (0.1%) for twice as many blocks, which is not getting paid back in data adaptation due to the source of the data being random.

Pure random data cannot be compressed without losses. Moreover, compression implementations add headers and metadata.
So, you should try with some actual data for a more representative test.

OK, random could explain no difference between compression levels. But if PIGZ is built as Parralel Implementation of GZip, shouldn't their result be the same?

That is a somewhat strong assumption. What I know from bz2 (which is different from gzip) is that in order to multithread the data is split into n parts, each of which are compressed seperately (with their own metadat etc). This gives different (usually worse) results from considering the entire piece of data. I would imagine that a multithreaded gzip has a similar tradeoff.

The "original data" is a few genomics data files of over 50 GB each. I assumed running real comparison test would take quite some time, so decided to run this mock comparison to figure out details.

@Araneus0390 You should have used head on your original data for your tests, instead of using random data. Random data will tell you nothing about compression, and will certainly tell you nothing about what to expect for your data.

@MarkAdler, you mean, use somesing like cat original_file | head -c 1000000000 > file1.txt and use that as he file(s) for tryouts?

@Araneus0390 Exactly.
